# Non-obsolete comments being deleted

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation

[This question of mine](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18811/13767) had a number of comments that

- asked for more information on the specific requirements, or
- discussed the tags attached to the question.

The requirements that had been asked for have been added to the question, but - at least the last time I had seen the comments - not all questions regarding the tagging have been solved. In particular, somebody added a mind-mapping tag to my question, and then somebody else asked whether a mind-mapping tag really was necessary (since this would be the first question using it).

Now, all comments have been deleted. This feels wrong to me. The tag is still there, and I can't find any related question on meta where this has been discussed. I do not know whether there has been any further discussion on the topic, or which were the reasons to keep the tag (and who decided to do so).

Is this really how such things are meant to be handled?

I have seen [this related question on deleted comments](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/650/why-are-comments-deleted) but I feel it has a different focus, since I would not consider the comments related to the question tags obsolete. Other people may come along, see the single use of the mind-mapping tag, and then ask the same question again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments by nature are transient - both mods, and posters can delete them, and that's what's happened here. In general if its useful for the question it goes in the question or an answer. If its meta-ish, like this, they should go in meta.

In short, I think this is what should have happened.

If the tagging thing is still an issue, it might be a question for meta. IMO it didn't quite belong there anyway.

Comment: You're right of course; the tagging issue probably didn't belong there in the first place.

Comment: @jhin: To recap what happened: I created+added the [tag:mind-mapping] tag, Izzy wondered if that’s a useful tag, I explained why I do think it is, and while he was not convinced, we left it at that, and deleted our comments. I think there was no need to go to Meta for this as it happened on the fly while retagging/improving your question. However, if Izzy, or anyone else, thinks that we should not keep the tag, a discussion about this can be opened here on Meta.

Comment: Thanks for the summary, @unor. As pointed out (multiple times already ;) those comments didn't deal with the question itself, but were rather "meta-ish" (nice word, Journeyman ;) – whether a tag is needed or not is a topic for Meta, not for the main site. Let me just link a related Meta-Q: [Merge “knowledge-base” and “knowledge-organization”?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1169/185) :D